Ошибка при подключении автопостинга к боту discord
Хотел подключить автопостинг к своему боту в дискорд, почему-то выдает ошибку в 15 строке main.py(прикрепил скрин), помогите и объясните пожалуйста
Код main.py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", help_command=None,intents=disnake.Intents.all()) 


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Bot {bot.user} is ready to work! ")


for file in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
    
    
bot.run("токен бота убрал что-бы не украли")

Код постинга
class Post(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):

        await self.post_message()

    async def post_message(self):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
        await channel.send(MESSAGE)
        await asyncio.sleep(30)  # 2 часа в секундах
        await self.post_message()

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Post(bot))


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55231877/6808809

@EvgeniyZ , я не нашёл решения моей проблемы в этом посту. Все что было описано в посте и комментариях к нему у меня было установлено правильно

Ну тогда код обновляйте в вопросе, чтоб в нем было все "правильно", или делайте пометки того, что пробовали... Я вот открываю ссылку и вижу первое решение: change bot.add_cog("cogs.fun") to bot.load_extension("cogs.fun"), в вопросе я вижу у вас bot.add_cog, что противоречит тому решению.
